# How can a string be both callable and a string?

Tags: php, variables

I have the following, very weird, code:

```
$var = 'key';

var_dump(is_callable($var)) // true;
var_dump(is_string($var)) // true;
```

How can one variable be both callable and a string? And when I set the `$var` variable to another string. `is_callable()` will return `false` (what I think is normal behavior).

What is going on here? Why is this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks callable to me: http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

Comment: `key` is a function you can use it like `$var($myArray)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `key` is a core PHP function, thus callable: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

```
$var = 'keyy'; //Notice the extra y

var_dump(is_callable($var)); // false;
var_dump(is_string($var)); // true;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This is indeed the reason for this behaviour. Fixed it by using `$key instanceof Closure`.